# if var > then div display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, var

I have a variable `lineNum` that increment when I click on `h1`

I am trying to make '`if`' make a `div display:none`, but I just cant type the `if` code right?

Here is the `if` JQuery line I am having trouble with below:

```
if (lineNum > 1) {blue-sun-div, display: none;}
```

thank you for your help : )

---

***EDIT: 
hello
here is the jquery code I have made ( my first jquery coding project)

Two divs move across the screen when I click 'h1'and 'h2', 'var' also increments. When 'var' goes 1 or above: blue-sun-div should disappear.

I can make the blue-sun-div disapear if I refresh the browser but only whilst i manually enter 'var' =1 or more ,so I have the div-name correct, but it will not disappear when lineNum++ raises the var 'lineNum' past 1 automatically.

Do I need to re trigger the code at the end, after lineNum does its job? 
sorry if this does not make sense. its 4am here.

here is the code.  thank you very much

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var lineNum = 0;

$("h1").click(function() {
    $("#blue-sun-div, #red-sun-div").animate({
            "left": "+=200px"
    }, 1000);
  });

$("h2").click(function() {
    $("#blue-sun-div, #red-sun-div").animate({
            "left": "-=200px"
    }, 1000);
  });

lineNum++;

if(lineNum > 1) {
    $("#blue-sun-div").css({ display: "none" });
}

})
```

Comment: Your `lineNum++` only gets called when the document gets created. it does not get called each time something happens on the page. Move the `lineNum++` into the click function of either your h1 or h2, or both if necessary. This will make the lineNum increment each time the h1/2 tag is clicked.

Comment: see: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fYvWJ/) for a simple example

Answer (score 1):

To make an element have css `display: none`, you can use the following method:

Pure JavaScript:

```
if(lineNum > 1) {
    document.getElementById("blue-sun-div").style.display = "none";
}
```

With JQuery (I recommend this)

```
if(lineNum > 1) {
    $("#blue-sun-div").css({ display: "none" });
}
```

This is assuming you have a `<div id="blue-sun-div"> ...`.

Comment: hello thank you everyone. i am having trouble posting my code i shall post as soon as i can, thank you very much : )

Comment: thanks Geof, i can make the div disappear now, but i think the lineNum++ might not be incrementing or not refreshing? This is my first day with jquery, I have added my code now, I appreciate your help : )

Comment: In your jQuery code, `line++` is only called once, when the document is ready. It will not be `++`'d anywhere else. You should put `line++` in an event handler, wherever that makes sense.

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you, I would appreciate an upvote or accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

do you have access to jquery? or are you just using plain javascript?

the easiest way would be:

```
if(lineNum > 1)
{
   $('#blue-sun-div').hide();
}
```

this assumes that you have jquery setup already and that `blue-sun-div` is the id of the div (`<div id="blue-sun-div">`)

if it is the class (`<div class="blue-sun-div">`) then the jquery above needs to change to `$('.blue-sun-div').hide();`

for plain javascript, the best way would be to create a hide function and call it in the onclick of the h1.

in your javascript:

```
function hideDiv(divId){
   document.getElementById(divId).style.display="none";
}
```

then in the html:

```
<h1 id="SomeID" onclick="hideDiv('blue-sun-div');">H1 TEXT</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do:
if `blue-sun-div` is a classname

```
if(lineNum>1){
  $(".blue-sun-div").hide();
}
```

if `blue-sun-div` is an ID

```
if(lineNum>1){
  $("#blue-sun-div").hide();
}
```

Comment: hello thank you, I can make the div disappear now, but i think the lineNum++ is not refreshing my script or something along the lines. or maybe the 'var' is not incrementing up? I have added more code, thank you very much for your help Francis.